# laravel5.5 Cache can't get in console or tinker

Tags: caching, console, laravel-5.5, tinker

I use laravel5.5 and on console or tinker use cache object,but i try use cache in console or tinker, is return null!Why? I found just use reids object is ok, but try to exchang cache dirve also wrong!